List to Lists in Haskell
I have a CSV file with 2 columns and each one with 32100 rows. I need to import this data and separate each column into a list of lists with a thousand values each list. E.g., let column2_data = [[1,2,3,4,], [3,4,6,7], ...] (Note: the data is of type float)."
import Data.Csv
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as BL
import qualified Data.Vector as V


parserCsv :: IO ()
parserCsv = do
    csvData <- BL.readFile "src/file.csv"
    case decode NoHeader csvData of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right v -> V.forM_ v $ \(x, y) ->
            putStrLn $ show (y :: Float) ++ " // " ++ show (y :: Float)

I need to import this data and separate each column into a list of lists with a thousand values each list. E.g., let column2_data = [[1,2,3,4,], [3,4,6,7], ...] (Note: the data is of type float).
And I have a Main.hs
module Main (main) where

import Lib
import CSVConverter
import Data.Text (pack)
import qualified Data.Vector as Vector
import Parser

main :: IO ()
main = do
    parserCsv.

The parserCsv module should return a list of lists like this:
let dados1 = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ...], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0, ...], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0,...] ...]
let dados2 = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]]
with the data from both columns, inside a list as other lists with 1000 values each.

I would separate the logic to turn it into lists, with:
groupAt :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupAt n = go
  where go [] = []
        go xs = ys : go zs
            where ~(ys, zs) = splitAt n xs

and then use this to process the result of the decoding:
parserCsv :: IO ([[Float]], [[Float]])
parserCsv = do
    csvData <- BL.readFile "src/salary.csv"
    case decode NoHeader csvData of
        Left err -> error err
        Right v -> pure (groupAt 1000 (V.toList (fmap fst v)), groupAt 1000 (V.toList (fmap snd v)))


Variable not in scope:
toList
:: ((a3 -> b2) -> f1 a3 -> f1 b2)
-> ((a4, b3) -> a4) -> V.Vector a5 -> [a6]
A compiler generated this error. Basically, the structure of the CSV is like this:
0,0.084361
0.01,0.040756
0.02,-0.017995
0.03,0.005326
0.04,0.24274
0.05,-0.13293
0.06,0.048932

@DiógenesJúnior: V.toList.

I had already applied V.toList, but other problems appeared.
Couldn't match type ‘(,) [[a1]]’ with ‘IO’
Expected: IO ([[Float]], [[Float]])
Actual: ([[a1]], ([[Float]], [[Float]]))
And many other problems appeared.

@DiógenesJúnior: I forgot the pure/return.

Onsem
I might have mistaken in explaining the question.
The two columns of the CSV should be two separate lists. Each of these lists should contain another 32 lists, with 1000 values in each of them.
this csv is like this
First colum is time: 1,2,3,4 ...
And the second is the value: 0,21312 ; 1,312312

@DiógenesJúnior: yes, normally that is the case, it returns an IO ([[Float]], [[Float]]), so a 2-tuple with lists of lists of floats.

Where I put pure/return in code? Its my first time with haskell haha

Now its run !!. Can you help again, please?
How do I take these lists and pass them to another list that is in another module called main?

import Lib
import Parser

main :: IO ()
main = do
    parserCsv

I need a list like this : let dados = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0, 9.0]] wih the second column data to using in calculation of the average.

@DiógenesJúnior: is it possible to edit the question with the relevant function and explain what you aim to do?

@DiógenesJúnior: you can use (dados1, dados2) <- parserCsv in the main, and then thus continue in the do block with these.
